# my write method fails to generate output

Tags: javascript, methods, prototype

Anyone have a clue why write method isn't working here?  The script is intended to just reverse a prompt string.  Nothing extraordinary, but the write method fails.

**JS in head**

```
String.prototype.backwards = function(){
var out='';
for (var i = this.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    out += this.substr(i,1);
    }
return out;
}
```

**BODY**

```
var inString=prompt("Enter test string: ");
document.write(inString.backwards());
```

prompt works.  write method fails.
Code is accurate as far as I can tell.  Also I use jShint but isn't helping.  And my browser's dev tools didn't really pin point anything.

FYI code is from ch8 of "learn JS in 24hrs" kindle version....

Comment: JS is case sensitive, the String constructor has a capital s, you should be seeing a ReferenceError on your JS console

Comment: It is `String` not `string`.

Comment: that fixed is there anyway I can check via the browser tools or sublime?

Comment: F12(at least in Windows environments) in most browsers will bring up the Developers tools where you can tab over to a JS console

Comment: Don't use `document.write`. It's not 1998, and unless you know why you're using a datastream write command (with context resetting on a newly opened stream), you have no idea why you're using it. Use proper 2016 DOM manipulation. Create a `<p>` element, set its `.textContent` value, then append it to `document.body` or something.

Comment: ... and the console Patrick mentioned will show you errors with your code, in this case probably something like `string.prototype is undefined`.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Or, `document.body.textContent += str`.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans you are right of course, but the code is copied from a book, not hand-cranked

Comment: @PatrickEvans no ref error comes up. I use sublime 3 w/ jshint ... jshint tho recommended semis after each nested closing bracket....   also can I delete the question before people down vote or is there any consequence to that?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 covered by the "or something", but yes, if you don't want the input marked up, just straight up modify the body's textContent.

Comment: @Rhumborl that is insane. `document.write`, used in the body, can *reset the entire document context, wiping any and all code currently active*. No tutorial or book should be advocating `document.write`. No tutorial or book should be advocating extending/modifying native Object prototypes, either...

Comment: @chignon Copy-pasting your code into my browser console works fine. What exactly is happening, or not happening, when you run it?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I am using Sams "Learn JS in 24 hrs" kindle version.   The code is verbatim from ch8

Comment: @chignon that book is from 2002. It's absolutely unsuited to teaching you modern JavaScript (and I don't mean the cutting edge new syntax, just basic JavaScript) or best practices. Using this book is a bad idea, get a [recent O'Reilly book on JS](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920035534.do) instead.

Comment: @Rhumborl the code works fine now.  Since it's on my tablet I actually rewrite all the code.  The idea is that so get to bang out as much code as I can.  I write it out on Sublime and then copy/paste on Stack

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I have ed 6 (2015)  but actually do know any better ones I'm open .  A lot of the code here is in snippets.

Comment: most recently written O'Reilly ones are pretty good (2013 and later, you don't want "updated" reprints from before 2012 really). I linked to a very recent one that coves JS basics in the previous comment that should be a good modern explanation.